# Is there a way to group react-router-dom v6 routes together in another component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'd like to compartmentalize my code a little bit and I found out I can only have Route components inside Route components. The components are returning routes, but react-router-dom is being too smart and denying it.

My research only found how to add components to the Route's `element` param, but it doesn't work with nested routes the way I am trying to get it to work. For example, creating a PrivateRoute or something like that but I'm trying to group routes together by page.

Let's say I have routes like so:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="page1">
    <Route path=":id" />
    <Route path="" />
  </Route>
  <Route path="page2">
    <Route path=":id" />
    <Route path="" />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

I would like to group the page1 and page2 routes in their own components like so:

```
function Page1Routes(props) {
  ...
  return (
    <Route path="page1">
      <Route path=":id" />
      <Route path="" />
    </Route>
  )
}
```

and then use them in my `Routes` like so:

```
<Routes>
  <Page1Routes />
  <Page2Routes />
</Routes>
```

Unfortunately, react-router-dom is having a fit about this, but I don't feel like this really breaks the paradigm of routes only under a route since the return function is returning Routes.

Am I going in the wrong direction? Or is there a way for this to work like this?

Comment: How about saving all routes inside an object with the parent name as the page name and then exporting this object and looping over it and mapping the content to a Route component?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

`routes.js`:

```js
const page1 = [
  {
    path: "/",
    component: <Home />,
  },
  {
    path: "/profile",
    component: <Profile />,
  },
];

const page2 = [
  {
    path: "/about",
    component: <About />,
  },
];

export const routes = [...page1, ...page2];
```

`App.js`:

```js
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import routes from "./routes";

function App() {
  return (
      <Routes>
        {routes.map((route, index) => {
          const { path, component } = route;
          <Route key={index} path={path} element={component}></Route>;
        })}
      </Routes>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The problem is that here there's no children route, but you can figure a way to have children's or just write the whole path name again